# How to turn a string into a ClassName and execute a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dynamic, models

My question is how to make it possible to have a function that takes a string convert it to a class and than execute a linq query.
This is a simple example of how it should work:

```
 // DBContext
 DataView _db = new DataView();

 public static void ... (){
       Create("somedesc", "someabbr", "vwFunctieScheidingMetacom", "someiconstring");
 }
 // the function
 public static void Create(string description, string abbrevition, string cn, string icon)
 {
        // cn is classname
        // convert cn into a class
        var class = Convert.Class(cn);
        // Execute Linq query
        _db.class.ToList<dynamic>();
 }
```

This is my dbcontext:

```
public partial class DataView : DbContext
{
    public DataView()
        : base("name=DataView")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<vwFunctieScheidingMetacom> vwFunctieScheidingMetacom { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

Now there is only one model loaded, but in the future there will be more. these models will all be different and I want to make it as dynamic as possible.

I tried to use reflection but it didn't work yet, i have no idea where to start.
Any help would be appreciated.

## update

This is one of the class that needs to be used dynamicly:

```
namespace Portal.ModelViews
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

[Table("vwFunctieScheidingMetacom")]
public partial class vwFunctieScheidingMetacom
{
    public int? PermissiesID1 { get; set; }

    public int? PermissiesID2 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string PermName1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string PermName2 { get; set; }

    public string Omschrijving { get; set; }

    public int? Prioriteit { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int FunctieScheidingID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(60)]
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: How is the application supposed to create a class with properties, methods etc out of a string ? I know methods with which you can create an instance of an object of an class you already specified out of an anonymus type (if the properties of the anonymus type and the properties of the specified class correspond) but creating a class itself out of a string ? That is something I would be happy to see explained ;)

Comment: You want the string to be the name of the existing class to fetch? Probably need ExecuteQuery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472059/dynamic-table-name-in-entity-framework-linq or reflection https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d54815dc-4233-4697-9859-17356eb92f36/could-i-access-object-through-object-namestring-in-ef?forum=adonetefx#dbe631df-8836-40bd-bac8-894389249381

Comment: @SteveGreene Yes I do, but I am going to use it by different situations not only the queries. And how do I use reflection on this problem?

Comment: _db.GetType().GetProperty("table").GetValue(_db,null) would be your context.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't seem to like the answers so far I'll interpret your question differently. Put references to your classes in a dictionary.

Assuming your code defines a class Foo...

```
var clash = new Dictionary< string, Type>();
clash["Foo"] = Foo.GetType();
```

Populate this hash table with your strings and the types to which they resolve.

Comment: My question next is... How to use that to get the results from the database.. I know this doesnt work _db.clash["Foo"].ToList<dynamic>(). Any idea how I need to do that?